# Multiple models in one view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems like it should be easy but I can't figure out how to do it:

If a user is logged into my app I always want to display their name in the top right of the navbar. But if they are in a different view, for example the Posts view from the Posts controller than that view only has access to the Post class and its associated variable right? So how can I plug this is:

```
<%= user.name %>
```

When I didn't go through the User controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that many Rails apps define a method called `current_user` in a base controller like `ApplicationController` and then make it available as a view helper:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    # Do whatever logic you need to return an instance of the logged in user
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Then you can reference that method in any controllers or views that inherit from that class:

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```

Your controllers can call any model that you want, so that assumption stated in your question is not true. (For example, you could call the `User` model from your `Posts` controller if you *really* wanted to.)